# how to store req.body.state in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, backend, clarifai

This is the backend section of the server in node js

```
stub.PostWorkflowResults(
  
    {
        workflow_id: "Demographics",
        inputs: [
        {data: {//need req.body.input here //}}
    ]
},

    metadata,
    (err, response) => {
   if(response){
    console.log(response)
   }else {
       console.log(err)
   }
```

I used bodyparser.  What needed is to put req.body.input inside the object `{data: {//need req.body.input here //}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FrontEnd

```
//App.js

import axios from 'axios'
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import './App.css';


function App() {
  const [something, setSomething] = useState({})
  const url = "http://localhost:5000/data"
  const input = "https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2015/06/06/15/Chris-Pratt.jpg"

  const func = async () => {
    const {data} = await axios.post(url, {input : input})
    setSomething(data)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    func()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>APP WORKING</h1>
      {console.log("something : ",something)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Backend

```
//demographics.js
const {ClarifaiStub, grpc} = require("clarifai-nodejs-grpc");
const stringify = require('json-stringify-safe');

const demographics = (req,res) => {
    const stub = ClarifaiStub.grpc()
    const metadata = new grpc.Metadata();
    metadata.set("authorization", "Key  #ClarifaiKey#");
    stub.PostWorkflowResults(
        {
            workflow_id: "Demographics",
            inputs: [
                {data: {image: {url: req.body.input}}}
            ]
        },

        metadata,
        (err, response) => {
            if(response){
                console.log("AGE :", response.results[0].outputs[4].data.regions[0].data.concepts[0])
   here -->     const data = stringify(response.results[0].outputs[4].data.regions, null, 2)
                res.send(data)
            }
            else {
                console.log(err)
                res.status(400)
            }
        }
    )
}


module.exports = {
    demographics: demographics
}
```

I am not very confident about 'json-stringify-safe' package but from what I could make out, nodejs-grpc clarifai returns a circular structure data object which would throw an error when used directly so "stringify(response.results[0].outputs[4].data.regions, null, 2)" converts it into a regular json object.

Demographics model works for multiple faces so if there are multiple faces in the picture then you can follow up from **"response.results[0].outputs[4].data.regions"**

Also, in server.js be sure to include

```
//server.js
...
const posts = require('./demographics.js')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.post('/data', posts.demographics)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not implementing the code like that?

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    stub.PostWorkflowResults(
    {
        workflow_id: "my-custom-workflow",
        inputs: [
            {
            data: {
                image: {
                    url: req.body.input // guessing that your input is a url
                }
            }
        }
    ]
    },
    metadata,
    (err, response) => {
    if (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
    }

    if (response.status.code !== 10000) {
        throw new Error("Post workflow results failed, status: " + response.status.description);
    }

    // Since we have one input, one output will exist here.
    const result = response.results[0]

    // One output is present for each model in the workflow.
    for (const output of result.outputs) {
        console.log("Predicted concepts for model: " + output.model.name);
        for (const concept of output.data.concepts) {
            console.log("\t" + concept.name + " " + concept.value);
        }
        console.log();
    }
}
);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do `console.log(req.body)` first, if you can't read the data, check 3 things.

1. Check if server router HTTP method is one of `post`, `put`, `delete`
2. Check if browser side HTTP calls right method and argument ex>`axios.post(url, data, config)`
3. Check if body parser is attached in same context. For example, if you did `app.use(bodyParser())` , all sub routes should be attached into `app` to refer `req.body`

If this check list doesn't work for you, please share *client-side* code and *server-side*router code for details.

Comment: Hi @hellikiam,
I have to make an api call to Clarifai. 
Clarifai shared this method of request in their documentation. Here i need to insert the image URL inside that `{data: {//image URL here//}}`. 
To insert the image URL from the front end, the fetch method is used. 
The problem here is to know the way of inserting the `app.post( '/' , (req, res) => req.body.input)` into to the `stub.PostWorkflowResults`